# Make profile picture a picture from an album without recreating it

Tags: facebook, photos, album, profile-picture

I have a picture in an album that I would like to make my profile picture, but it won't let me unless I crop it, making a new version. I would like to take my photo from my album, without having to create a new one (so my comments and likes do not erase), to my profile picture album. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your profile picture a photo that you already have uploaded in a different album, Facebook will automatically copy it (without the comments and likes) to the *Profile pictures* album (there is no other way unless you upload it directly as a profile picture). However, the original picture remains in the original album **with** all the likes and comments.

Comment: such a bummer! but thanks!